# How can make a shadow for button in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making my application on Android. I want to design a button like this:
[image]
but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me!!!
Thanks you all!!

Comment: Use FloatingActionButton https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/floating-action-button#:~:text=A%20floating%20action%20button%20(FAB,and%20respond%20to%20button%20taps.

Comment: @Javlon Thanks for your reply. I'm using FloatingActionButton but I can make a shadow like this. A shadow in my FAB is like a rectangle

Comment: Maybe you have the elevation set too high.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I set evelation is low but the shadow is not like in the image